# PHP order multi-dimensional array by three or more values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array like this one

```
array(
[0] => Array (
       [fullAddress] => 2482 Midvale St,Kettering, OH, 45420
       [bedrooms] => 3
       [bathrooms] => 1.0
       [sqft] => 1548
       [yearBuilt] => 1955
       [lastSoldDate] => 12/09/2015
       [lastSoldPrice] => 87,000
       [distance] => 0.59
       )
[1] => Array (
       [fullAddress] => 2828 Vale Dr, Dayton, OH, 45420
       [bedrooms] => 3
       [bathrooms] => 1.5 
       [sqft] => 1356 
       [yearBuilt] => 1956 
       [lastSoldDate] => 10/09/2015 
       [lastSoldPrice] => 117,500 
       [distance] => 0.38
) 
[2] => Array (
       [fullAddress] => 2812 Vale Dr, Dayton, OH, 45420 
       [bedrooms] => 4 
       [bathrooms] => 2.0 
       [sqft] => 1248 
       [yearBuilt] => 1955 
       [lastSoldDate] => 05/13/2015 
       [lastSoldPrice] => 114,900 
       [distance] => 0.33
 )
)
```

I need to order: distance asc, lastSoldPrice desc (Most recent date to current date) and at last order by same bedrooms, bathrooms and sqft within 20% +-. comparing to a principal property like this one:

```
Array (
       [fullAddress] => 2400 Ghent Ave, Dayton, OH 45420
       [bedrooms] => 3 
       [bathrooms] => 1.0 
       [sqft] =>  984
       [yearBuilt] => 1956
       [lastSoldDate] => 05/06/2014 
       [lastSoldPrice] => 74,763
 )
```

So the first two orders are ready and im able to order by distance and lastsoldprice with usort() but I havent get the last one yet 'cause I don't know how to compare to another array (principal property).

This is the code I'm using with usort

```
function sort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['distance']==$b['distance']) {
        if ($a['lastSoldDate']==$b['lastSoldDate']) {
           return 0;
        } else {
            return ($a['lastSoldDate']<$b['lastSoldDate']) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    } else {
        return ($a['distance']>$b['distance']) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

usort($propertydata, 'sort');
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'within 20% + or -'? Should houses that don't fit within that range not be shown at all? Or clumped together at the end?

Comment: I forgot to add that information so I edit the question. Same bedrooms, bathrooms and sqft within 20% + or - comparing to a searched address who has the same data. That would be the last priority sort.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that answers my question. Maybe you could add the 'searched address who has the same data' to your question, as well as the order you expect the results to be in?

Comment: You could use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) - then perhaps a sort using a `Closure` to implement the formula on distance?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to first sort the array by square feet, and then by distance and last sold price.

Like so

```
function sort1($a, $b) {
    if ($a['bedrooms']!=$b['bedrooms'] || $a['bathrooms']!=$b['bathrooms'] || $a['sqft']==$b['sqft']) {
       return 0;
    } else {
        return (abs($a['sqft']-$b['sqft'])<$a['sqft']*.2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}


function sort2($a, $b) {
    if ($a['distance']==$b['distance']) {
        if ($a['lastSoldDate']==$b['lastSoldDate']) {
           return 0;
        } else {
            return ($a['lastSoldDate']<$b['lastSoldDate']) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    } else {
        return ($a['distance']>$b['distance']) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

usort($propertydata, 'sort1');
usort($propertydata, 'sort2');
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, but first, sort1 function should also compare beds and baths?

Comment: @DanielDuque See edit. Now the first sorting algo ignores those properties with different beds/bathrooms. Note that you might need to tinker with this to get it perfect, but having two or more sorts is probably the direction you need to go in.

Comment: Thanks, im going to try it and i'll let you know on any progress